# C++ Comparing inner values in a 2D multidimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

So I'm busy coding a 3x3 2D tic-tac-toe game, I want to convert it to 3D version soon- something a friend showed me.

Anyway, I have most of the fundamentals down (Player 1, Player 2, inputting values for rows and columns and so on. But I've gotten stuck comparing whether the row of values or column of values are equal to each other.

```
constexpr size_t rows = 3;
constexpr size_t cols = 3;

char gameBoard[rows][cols] = {
{'-','-','-'},
{'-','-','-'},
{'-','-','-'}
};
```

If this were changed through the input process to:

```
char gameBoard[rows][cols] = {
{'O','O','O'},
{'X','X','-'},
{'-','-','X'}
};
```

I would like it to recognize that row 1 is now full and i can give necessary output.

I wanted to use a `for` loop and check the equality between the first char to the second `&&` third but for some reason when I do this it seems to just simply give the output "win text" that I've given it.

Thanks for any input given :)

***So this question was answered, but I just wanted to give my code of what I did** to test the rows and columns. I haven't included my Diagonal section since i'm just finishing it up, but it should be pretty straight forward (instead of `[i][j]` you have `[j][j]` to test the diagonals from top left to bottom right, for example).

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != 1; i++)
        {
            int win_cnt = 0;
            for (size_t j = 0; j != 3; j++)
            {
                if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'X')
                {
                    win_cnt++;
                    if (win_cnt == 3)
                    {
                        system("cls"); //Please do not mind this, this is a placeholder
                        cout << "\n Player 1 has won the game!" << endl;
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }//Check for row win

            win_cnt = 0;
            for (size_t j = 0; j != 3; j++)
            {
                if (gameBoard[j][i] == 'X')
                {
                    win_cnt++;
                    if (win_cnt == 3)
                    {
                        system("cls"); //Please do not mind this, this is a placeholder
                        cout << "\n Player 1 has won the game!" << endl;
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }//Check for column win
        }//Check for win PRIMARY
```

Do not mind the use of system, i'm in the process of coding a function to clear the used "console" screen. system("cls") is just a faster way to debug right now.

Comment: Show us the code of what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry Mahesh, I find posting all of my code would be slightly irrelevant as I would like to understand what i'm doing and implement an answer I get from SO into my code. I just couldn't figure out if there was some fancy way of doing an iterate through my array or if I literally use two loops to check the equality of 'O' vs 'X' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
// Check rows
for (int row=0; row<rows; ++row) {
  char first = gameBoard[row][0];
  int col = 1;
  while (gameBoard[row][col]==first && col<cols) ++col;

  if (col==cols-1) return new std::string(first) + " wins"!;
}
```

Similarly you can check columns and diagonals

Comment: Thank you, worked brilliantly after I edited it to fit in with my code :)

Comment: You're welcome. Accept the answer that solved your problem and upvode the other answers that helped you.

Comment: Is there a specific way to set it as answered? I tried up-voting but it wouldn't allow me to do so since I have not gained 15 points yet

Comment: There is a check mark under the voting arrows. That's the way.

Comment: I did so, thank you. I also posted the code I actually used, yours primarily gave me the idea for it.

Answer (score 0):

The naive and simplest solution is to have two loops, one to check if all three are equal to `'O'` and if not then run another to check if all three are equal to `'X'`.

Something like the following pseudo-code:

```
winner = check_winner('O');
if (winner != 'O')
    winner = check_winner('X');

if (winner != '-')
    std::cout << "The winner is " << winner << '\n';
```

The function `check_winner` will of course do the actual check, and returns the symbol or `'-'` if no winner.

Comment: Thank you, I actually used yours along with MarvinLabs's, which helped to work out player 2's code as well.